# PHP 404 contact form on SPA

Tags: php, forms, single-page-application, contacts

New to PHP-
ran through tutorials and several other threads regarding this issue and I'm struggling quite a bit.  I am creating a single page application without a framework and currently running on localhost.  Upon submitting the form, I am greeted with a message that says `Cannot POST /mail.php`

I figure I have the mail.php file in the wrong spot, so I moved it around in every single directory until I decided to just put a copy of it in EVERY directory to try and get something to work.  I even posted it in the contact.js file.

contact.js

```
import AbstractView from "./AbstractView.js";

export default class extends AbstractView {
  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  async getHtml() {
    return `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="contact">
        <form action="mail.php" method="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br />
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br />
          <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"><br />
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="25" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br />
          </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          <div style="float: right"><button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;
  }
}
```

mail.php

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $header = "From: ".$name."<".$email.">\r\n";

    $recipient = "MYEMAIL@gmail.com";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $header)
    or die("Error sending mail");

    echo "messsage sent";
  }

?>
```

file structure

[image: filestructure]

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which way do you access the index.html. Does localhost/index.html work for you?

Comment: index.html works.
it serves up index.js that manages routes under a static folder. then based on the path serves up the individual view component -

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an HTTP server which can execute PHP programs.

You appear to have written your own server using Node.js then it won't support PHP unless you have designed it - explicitly - to do so (and you'd be better off using server-side JS instead of PHP if you were already in a Node.js ecosystem).

Comment: nodemailer it is :/